# How to compute permutations with postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large database with connections between cities. Each connection has a start and destination town, a start date, and a price for that connection.

I'd like to compute any combinations of outgoing+return connections, for any connections, and for dates where the return connection is between 1-20 days. Then select the best price for each *date combination*.

Example:

Table:

```
city_start,     city_end,   date_start,     price
Hamburg         Berlin      01.01.2016      100.00
Berlin          Hamburg     10.01.2016      112.00
Berlin          Hamburg     10.01.2016      70.00
Berlin          Hamburg     12.01.2016      50.00
Berlin          Hamburg     30.02.2016      20.00
Paris           Madrid      ...
Madrid          Paris
London          Paris
```

Desired result:

```
Hamburg-Berlin-Hamburg, 01.01.2016, 10.01.2016, 170.00 (100+70)
Hamburg-Berlin-Hamburg, 01.01.2016, 12.01.2016, 150.00 (100+50)
...
(not Berlin-Hamburg on 30.02.2016 because it's >20 days from departure drive)
(not London-Paris, as there is no return Paris-London)
```

I can get the possible combinations by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_start, city_end, city_end, city_start from table
```

But how can I now compute their permutations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query to get all pairs uses a `join`:

```
select tto.city_start, tto.city_end, tto.date_start, tfrom.date_end,
       (tto.price + tfrom.price) as price
from t tto join
     t tfrom
     on tto.city_end = tfrom.city_start and
        tto.city_start = tfrom.city_end and
        tfrom.date_start >= tto.date_start + interval '1 day' and
        tfrom.date_end <= tto.date_start + interval '20 day';
```

To get the cheapest price, use window functions:

```
select tt.*
from (select tto.city_start, tto.city_end, tto.date_start, tfrom.date_end,
             (tto.price + tfrom.price) as price,
             row_number() over (partition by tto.city_start, tto.city_end order by (tto.price + tfrom.price) asc) as seqnum
      from t tto join
           t tfrom
           on tto.city_end = tfrom.city_start and
              tto.city_start = tfrom.city_end and
              tfrom.date_start >= tto.date_start + interval '1 day' and
              tfrom.date_end <= tto.date_start + interval '20 day'
      ) tt
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work in general. Is there an alternative to the row_number partition part? (because the windowAggr functions performance is quite poor)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without the row_number partition part:

```
SELECT
    a.city_start, a.city_end, b.city_end, a.date_start, b.date_start,
    min(a.price + b.price)
FROM
    flight AS a
    JOIN
    flight AS b ON a.city_start = b.city_end AND a.city_end = b.city_start
WHERE b.date_start BETWEEN a.date_start + 1 AND a.date_start + 20
GROUP BY a.city_start, a.city_end, b.city_end, a.date_start, b.date_start;
```

Comment: That's also great thanks. One question: what if I want to select a property outside the `group by`? Eg `a.carName`?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't see carName in the data. I would need to see that in the context of the rest of the data to be able to answer the question...

Comment: If course the question shows just an example. Just assume each row has an additional column `carName`. The question is: if not within group by, how can I then select this value

Comment: Choose the carName for the outgoing or the return trip?

Comment: Preferably for both.

Comment: Is the combination of city_start, city_end, date_start, and price unique?

Comment: No probably not, but I'm just interested in the bestprice entry.

Comment: Okay, but if that combination is not unique, then how will you know which carName value to choose if you have more than one record with the best price?

Comment: I want to chose the record with the best price. simply. Then get the `carName` of *that* bestprice entry.

Comment: I know. But if city_start, city_end, date_start, and price are not necessarily unique, then two records might have the best price. And those two records might have different values for carName.

Comment: For example, you might have two flights from Berlin to Hamburg on 1/1/16 that both cost $50. But they might have different values for carName.

Comment: OK I see, then I don't mind which record is chose (if the price is equal). It's fine just chosing one of them. But in this case the `carName` should of course come from the record that actually has been chosen. I might want to retrieve furher values from that record (not just the `carName`. But if I can get one, I get can all. And I don't know how I could get this one).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109571/discussion-between-david-aman-and-membersound).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include additional columns, try the following:

```
SELECT
    a.city_start, a.city_end, b.city_end, a.date_start, b.date_start,
    a.price + b.price, a.car_name, b.car_name
FROM
    flight AS a
    JOIN
    flight AS b ON a.city_start = b.city_end AND a.city_end = b.city_start
    LEFT JOIN
    flight AS c ON
         a.city_start = c.city_start
         AND
         a.city_end = c.city_end
         AND
         a.date_start = c.date_start
         AND (
             a.price > c.price
             OR (
                 a.price = c.price
                 AND
                 a.id > c.id))
    LEFT JOIN
    flight AS d ON
         b.city_start = d.city_start
         AND
         b.city_end = d.city_end
         AND
         b.date_start = d.date_start
         AND (
             b.price > d.price
             OR (
                 b.price = d.price
                 AND
                 b.id > d.id))
WHERE
    b.date_start BETWEEN a.date_start + 1 AND a.date_start + 20
    AND
    c.id IS NULL
    AND
    d.id IS NULL;
```